# If $U^{\lambda}T_{\lambda}^{\mu}=0$ and $U^{\lambda}$ is a vector, can we state that $T_{\lambda}^{\mu}$ is a tensor by the quotient rule?

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

Let's say we have a well defined non-zero vector $U^{\lambda}$, and some quantity $T_{\lambda}^{\mu}$. If we are told that

$$U^{\lambda}T_{\lambda}^{\mu}=0,$$

no matter the choice of coordinates, is it valid to use the quotient rule to state that $T_{\lambda}^{\mu}$ must be a tensor? Were we instead to have the relation that

$$U^{\lambda}T_{\lambda}^{\mu}=V^{\mu},$$

where $V^{\mu}$ is well defined non-zero vector, then $T_{\lambda}^{\mu}$ would definitely be a rank-two mixed tensor. My question is whether or not this rule also holds when $V^{\mu}$ is the zero vector.

Comment: What do you mean by $T^\mu_\lambda$ is quantity?

Comment: I mean some set of quantities which may or may not be components of a tensor.

Comment: But any square matrix $M$ can be seen as a bilinear form by $$M(v,u) = v^tMu$$

Comment: Which quotient rule are you referring to?

Comment: [Duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4158695/does-the-quotient-rule-hold-for-the-zero-tensor)

Comment: The so-called "quotient law" says that, given a set of quantities $T_{\mu\nu}$, if *for any vector* $A^\mu$ the quantities $B_\nu=A^\mu T_{\mu\nu}$ transform tensorially, then $T_{\mu\nu}$ transforms tensorially as well.
Note that $B_\nu=0$ is a special case, but I think you misunderstood what the quotient law says. It should be ANY vector $A^\mu$.

Comment: When you say it is a special case, do you mean that the quotient rule does not hold for $B_{\nu}=0$? 

Also, I apologise for the duplicate. That post was several weeks ago and since it didn't get any responses I forgot I ever posted it. I've deleted it now.

Comment: @ArcticChar I am referring to the rule as Jackozee Hakkiuz has described it above.